# Movie with humans in a floating cryopod where one believes an alien is his mother

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing this sci-fi movie in video stores on VHS but don't know the name. I'm guessing its close to late 70s but more likely an 80s movie. It's in color and I remember the graphics as decent. It's been some time so I'll give what I remember.

This is a movie that takes place in space.

There is a human (or at least appears human) male who seems to float around in a pod with a glass top. It looks like the cryo units in *Alien* but floats around.
He seems to believe an alien or creature is his mother, who tells him the humans who arrive will kill him.

The movie ends with him and a female seen flying through space (he allows her inside with him) as the only survivors of some sort of disaster.

Comment: Is there anything else you can remember about this film? Any art on the VHS box cover, the actors in it, anything at all? The more information we have, the more likely we are to dig up an answer for you.

Comment: Not really. At most I believe it was an American film but I don't really remember the actors in the film.

Comment: I do remember seeing the girl and guy floating in the pod in one still shot on the back. That's about it.

Comment: Damn it, this rings bells.  I think I saw something like this and thought it was a rip off of a Saberhagen berserker story. Googling various combos of "saberhagen berserker goodlife film" hasn't proved fruitful.  In case it helps.

Answer (score 3):

*Nightflyers* (1987), based on the George R.R. Martin novella?

I have not seen the movie, but I know one exists, and what you describe has similarities to the novella.

Plot summary from [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093626/plotsummary):

> Professor hires a spaceship to get to the source of weird signals from
>   deep space. The trip is cut short however when the ship's computer
>   gets jealous because the captain is in love with one of the female
>   passengers and it gets homicidal.

At least in the story, the ship's computer is an embodiment of the pilot's mother, which matches part of your description.  "She" wipes out most of the passengers.  The pilot can't physically contact the passengers because of an immune system problem. In the story he just stays in a separate part of the ship, but the glassed-in pod may serve the same function in the movie.