# 90s movie with psychics and an imploding spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie in the 90s.  I don't remember much, but here is what I do remember;

- The movie takes place on a spaceship, or set of spaceships.  I am not sure if there is more than one.
- The main character was a woman who gave me a Sharon Stone vibe.  She had some psychic abilities and classified herself as something like a level 4 (I might have the numbers mis-remembered the numbers).
- There is another character who ends up having a level 10.  Almost off the charts and we are all supposed to be impressed.  I think he ends up being a bad guy, but for the first part of the movie either he is an unknown psychic, or flying under the radar.
- The movie ends (maybe?) with the spaceship imploding.  I remember specifically it was "imploding" and not "exploding" as explained in the dialog.  However, it looked like a simple explosion to me, and my young mind was confused thinking there was no difference.
- There were no aliens - everyone was human (I think).
- I am pretty sure that the classification for the movie was R or PG-13.  I feel like there was some level of nudity.  Only bringing this up to eliminate TV series.

Comment: psych abilities defined as levels and 90's space reminds me of Babylon 5

Comment: @NKCampbell I don't think so.  There were no aliens and the movie had a PG-13 or R (at the time) vibe.  I think there might have even been nudity.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've never seen it and my answer relies heavily on this [film review](https://www.google.com/amp/s/mossfilm.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/george-r-r-martins-nightflyers-film-review/amp/), but I think this could be the movie **Nightflyers**. Based on the novella of the same name by George R R Martin, albeit loosely.

[image: Movie poster]

There's a class 3 female telepath (who could be considered Sharon Stone-ish) and a more powerful male telepath (potentially a psychic assassin).

[image: female character]

Originally released in 1987, so seeing it in the 90s fits in with the timeline, without it seeming that it was made much earlier.

There were no aliens, although they were looking for some.

The ship explodes at the end of the film. No idea if it was described as an implosion or not.

It was R rated in the US and an 18 in the UK.

No idea on the nudity.

Comment: It was remade into a TV series in 2018 as well, only watched the first episode, but pretty sure they had defined power levels for psychics, they had a male character who was very high level loaded on to the ship in a cage

Comment: This looks very promising!  I will check it out and see!

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The mention implosion at 1:02:05.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like the Babylon V episode "Mind War" (https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Mind_War)

Talia Winters is a mid-level telepath. Jason Ironheart is off-the-charts strong and getting stronger. At the end of the episode he transcends the physical and become something else entirely.
The "bad guy" could be Alfred Bester, the leader of the Psi Corps, who is a "P10", and (at this point in the series) the strongest telepath we have seen.

[Here is a scene with Winters and Ironheart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1G6yd51PS2A), where they discuss what was done to him.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Definitely not this one that I am thinking of though.

Answer (score 7):

Slight chance this is [Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_(1998_film)). It came out in 1998, it takes place on an undersea habitat (but one sent there to *investigate* a spaceship on the bottom of the ocean), I *think* I recall some discussion of ESP and a testing system for those abilities, the habitat does implode near the end (there's an explosion inside, but once the habitat ruptures, the huge water pressure outside crushes it like a tin can), and the female lead is, well, Sharon Stone.

Comment: No, I've watched Sphere and it is not the one I am thinking of in this case.  Thanks for posting though!